# Windows and OpenIddict authentiaction working together out of the box in abp.io Blazor WASM app

Tags: authentication, blazor-webassembly, abp.io

Could you please send or publish an example of an abp.io Blazor WASM solution that includes support for Windows authentication and OpenIddict authentication at the same time?
Also of interest is the scheme in which unsuccessful Windows authentication redirects the user to the standard SignIn page.
Thank you.

I tried the following:
https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/6204/windows-Authentication
But I had no success.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/19224) is the same question at GitHub.